# How to tell the boundary values of histogram bins in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

The data is a column extracted from another dataframe.

```
    Result
0   29
1   1
2   1
3   22
4   370
... ...
916 42
917 1
918 2200
919 200
920 770
```

Here is the graph with code `df.hist()`

[image]

Basically I want to find the boundary values on the `x-axis` of the first bin so as to separate it from the rest of the bins. How can I do this?

Comment: Assuming `df` is a pandas DataFrame, the corresponding [`hist`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html) function has 10 bins per default. So, the limits of the first bin should be something like `min(x)` and `max(x) / 10`, in the given example that might be `[0, 3500]`!? Without seeing the actual data, it's hard to provide more specific information.

Comment: @HansHirse the data has a `dataframe` format made from a `series` of bacteria plate count

Comment: Please find the data in the update. My guess is also around `3500`, but I wonder if I could find a more precise value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = df["columnName"]  # your data, a column from a pandas dataframe
no_of_bins = 10       # the default value for the hist function
min_value = min(x)
max_value = max(x)
bin_size = (max_value - min_value)/no_of_bins
print("Bin size", bin_size)
print("Min value", min_value)
print("Max value", max_value)

# Show the bin boundary values
# initiate values
lower_boundary = min_value
upper_boundary = min_value + bin_size

for i in range(no_of_bins):    
    print("[", lower_boundary, "-", upper_boundary, "]")
    lower_boundary = upper_boundary
    upper_boundary = upper_boundary + bin_size
```